# By default, how is the memory managed in a MPI envoriment?

Tags: linux, memory, cluster-computing, mpi

For instance, if each cluster has 4 CPU shared with 64G RAM, each CPU has 16 GB "local" ram sticked next to it (which is faster), if I assign tasks to these local nodes, ask one CPU to do one task, by default, does MPI task manager will let each CPU use its "local" RAM first?

Answer (score 1):

There is no general answer to that question, it highly depends on the specific System, Operating System and MPI Implementation. AFAIK the MPI specification does not address this.

For instance OpenMPI allows you to pin processes to cores/sockets, but does not do that by default. For details see [the OpenMPI FAQ](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=tuning#using-paffinity-v1.4)

A lot of the memory placement is up to the Operating System. For Linux there are a few articles that might give you a starting point:

[http://lwn.net/Articles/524977](http://lwn.net/Articles/524977/), [http://lwn.net/Articles/254445](http://lwn.net/Articles/254445/)